# Source of SetBuilder, Mapping, and Math

Tags: traditional-form, notation

Somewhere I obtained definitions of functions `SetBuilder`, `Mapping`, and `Math`, which produce traditional math expressions as output from such things as:

```
SetBuilder[x^2, x \[Element] Integers] // TraditionalForm

Mapping[Reals, Integers, 
  x \[RightTeeArrow] Floor[x]] // TraditionalForm

\[ScriptCapitalX]~
  Math["IsTopologicalSubspaceOf"]~\[ScriptCapitalY] // TraditionalForm
```

At one point within the past year I had access to those functions, as the preceding expressions did successfully evaluate. But not now.

Clearly these functions are not Mathematica 12.1 built-ins.

I think they may have come from the General Topology EntityStore, but I'm not finding them there now.

What package might be the source of these functions?

**Possible source**

In a comment, b3m2a1 says these functions look like they come from https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-62075-6_12.

I'm reading the relevant paper "Semantic representatton of general topology in the Wolfram language", by Ian Ford (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-62075-6_12( in that volume right now.

According to that paper, allegedly the functions at issue are in the `GeneralTopology Entity Store`. But I'm not finding them there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like it comes from this: https://books.google.com/books?id=dAUqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=Mathematica+%22SetBuilder%22&source=bl&ots=m9u3Hk_RYT&sig=ACfU3U3bkH61i8fwcyeHCnhHWNPzrqbXGg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmkbPmj6zoAhUUj54KHUKiB_UQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Mathematica%20%22SetBuilder%22&f=false

Comment: You should also check `Context[SetBuilder]`

Comment: Checking the context does no good, since I no longer have the function definition!

Answer (score 2):

The relevant developers have confirmed that there was a slight syntax change that affected the examples given in

https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/General-Topology-EntityStore

To make the functions available, evaluate

```
ResourceObject["General Topology EntityStore"];

store = ResourceData["General Topology EntityStore"];

EntityRegister[store];

EntityValue[Entity["GeneralTopologyTheorem"], "Activate"] // Activate;

EntityValue[Entity["GeneralTopologyTheorem"], 
    "TraditionalFormMakeBoxAssignments"] // Activate;
```

(notice `Entity` wrapped around the first argument in the last two commands)

which should put these `` GeneralTopology` `` functions on the `$ContextPath` and make the definitions for their usage messages available

```
 Information[{SetBuilder, Mapping, Math}]
```

as well as the corresponding traditional form typesetting rules.

Comment: OK, that explains why the symbols `SetBuilder`, `Mapping`, and `Math` were no longer accessible to me. However, even with that, the output from expressions with these is not what is originally was. For example, the output from `SetBuilder[x^2, x \[Element] Integers] // TraditionalForm` is SetBuilder(x^2, x in Z) where "x^2" is shown with a superscript, "in" is actually the usual "element of" symbol, and "Z" is actually the double-struck letter. But I'm pretty sure originally, the output was the same thing as what one would get from LaTeX `\{x^2 : x \in \mathbb{Z{\}`.

Comment: I was just informed by Ian Ford at WRI that one needs also to evaluate this to get the proper output from `SetBuilder`, etc.: `EntityValue[Entity["GeneralTopologyTheorem"], 
   "TraditionalFormMakeBoxAssignments"] // Activate;`

Comment: Updated with the typesetting information; I hope the correction will be made in the data repository pages soon.

Comment: I've informed both James Munkres, the author of the notebook, and WRI support.

Comment: I don't think James Munkres was involved with the notebook authoring. It is the theorem content etc. that is based on his topology textbook.